# Place selected float at end of document

Tags: floats, endfloat

Is there a way to make a float appear at the end of the document regardless of where it is placed in the source code?

With the `endfloat` package I could make all appearances of a float type flush to the end of the document, but I would like this to only happen to selected instances. I guess I could define a new custom float type and then have `endfloat` process only these custom floats, but I am wondering if there is a simpler solution.

Something like

```latex
\begin{figure}[e] % e for end of document
...
\end{figure}
```

would be great.

*(Alternatively, and even better for my use-case, would be a mechanism that would allow me to mark an entire section/subsection to be included in the appendix regardless of where it is actually placed in the source code.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any package for a convenient usage. However, one of the workarounds would be to save affected floats in a temporary file and read such the file at the end of a document. Here's one example

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand\movetoend{m}{%
  \immediate\write\writeendfigures{%
    \detokenize{#1}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \newwrite\writeendfigures
  \immediate\openout\writeendfigures=myfile.tmp}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \immediate\closeout\writeendfigures

  % This branch may need some tests s.a. \IfFileExists{myfile.tmp}{True}{False}
  \clearpage
  \newread\readendfigures
  \immediate\openin\readendfigures=myfile.tmp
  \loop
  \immediate\read\readendfigures to\linein
  \linein
  \ifeof\readendfigures
  \else\repeat

  \immediate\closein\readendfigures}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Image 1 in the text}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][2]

\movetoend{%
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Image 2 at the end}
  \end{figure}}

\kant[1][3]

\movetoend{%
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Image 3 at the end}
  \end{figure}}

\kant[1][4]

\begin{figure}[tbh]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.35\linewidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Image 2 in the text}
\end{figure}

\kant[1][5]
\end{document}
```

It produces these two pages

[image]

Comment: I have been using this solution and it works. The remaining drawback is that you have to pay attention that relative paths and any custom commands are still valid where the collected figure code lines are actually executed.

Answer (score 1):

figures are kept in order, so if one goes to the end, all following figures will go to the end.

If you set

```
 \setcounter{totalnumber}{0}
```

floats will not be placed on text pages until you increase it again, so floats with an option not including `p`  will not be placed (unless you over-ride the constraint with `!`)

If you want to allow `p` floats in the source but suppress float pages for some region, set

```
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{100}
```

so the minimum size required for a float page is not achievable,